# Deploy laravel app on a subdomain

Tags: laravel, deployment, laravel-4

I am new to laravel-4 and I want to deploy it on a sub domain.

In my root directory there is no folder or file and I don't have any administrative permission to manage this domain.

How can I deploy it?

Comment: Do you have access to some kind of admin panel where you can manage subdomains etc?

Comment: Ask your hosting how sub-domains map to your root directory?